# What is Diff between "contains" and "in" (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, contains, kotlin-android

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val input = "ABC"
    val output = "ABC,"
    println(input.contains(output,false))
    print(input in (output))
}
```

Output :

```
false 
true
```

I just checked that, `in` and `contains` are using same method, but why giving difference results.

Comment: You have it backwards. If input is in output, output contains input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kotlin [`contains`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/contains.html) function

> Returns true if this char sequence contains the specified other sequence of characters as a substring.

Actually, you're checking if `input.contains(output)`, and `"ABC"` does not contain `"ABC,"`.

The correct syntax is

```
println(output.contains(input,false))
```

Comment: Clearly Understood!! Thanks Man :)